# What Rights are required for a user to perform a RetrieveAttributeRequest?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin that is exporting an entity to another system.  Currently it is running as the current user, and for some roles I'm getting this error:

```
SecLib::CheckPrivilege failed. 
User: f64a1945-f91d-e211-a13b-0050569d79dd, 
PrivilegeName: prvReadAttribute, 
PrivilegeId: b8caea5d-f379-4295-aa59-38adeb73e853, 
Required Depth: Basic, BusinessUnitId: 9cc1eec6-2f1d-e211-ac61-005056870017
```

and for others it works just fine, but I have been unable to determine what rights have to be required...  The option set is a global option set if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These situations can be a little tricky, fortunately the error message (almost always) gives you the information you require.

In this case you are missing Read on 'Field' (under the customisations tab).

I knew this because, I opened this MSDN article: [Security Role UI to Privilege Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547441.aspx).

And did a search for `prvReadAttribute`.

Comment: You win 10 million Internets!